# ServiceLoader works different, when starting from JAR

Tags: java, maven, jar, serviceloader

We use external libraries for generating pdf-files with some specific content. As long as we run it as java program in the IDE, everything works as expected. But, when we build a jar with the maven-assembly-plugin, and then try to run this as a JAR Application, there is a problem.

Here's what happens. First of all, there are two dependencies, which we include in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.codeblock.qrinvoice.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>qrinvoice-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.codeblock.qrinvoice.openpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>qrinvoice-openpdf</artifactId>
    <version>1.11</version>
</dependency>
```

When we now debug to the problem point, we can see, that they use the `ServiceLoader` to load possible ServiceProviders...

```
public <T extends Service<?>> List<T> getAll(final Class<T> interfaceType) {
    final List<T> allServiceProviders = new LinkedList<>();
    ServiceLoader.load(interfaceType).iterator().forEachRemaining(allServiceProviders::add);
    return allServiceProviders;
}
```

... which will then load 3 possible ServiceProviders with the normal Java Programm:

```
allServiceProviders = {LinkedList@1397}  size = 3
 0 = {JavaGraphicsOutputWriterFactory@1403} 
 1 = {SvgOutputWriterFactory@1404} 
 2 = {IText4OutputWriterFactory@1405} "IText4OutputWriterFactory"
```

... but does only load 2 possible ServiceProviders when started from JAR:

```
allServiceProviders = {LinkedList@1397}  size = 2
 0 = {JavaGraphicsOutputWriterFactory@1403} 
 1 = {SvgOutputWriterFactory@1404}
```

The problem now is, that only the IText4OutputWriterFactory will print the pdf and therefore, running from JAR does not work.

A deeper look in the dependencies shows, that this class is in the second jar:

**First Jar:**

[image]
<sub>(source: [rennt.ch](https://rennt.ch/jar1.png))</sub>

**Second Jar:**

[image]
<sub>(source: [rennt.ch](https://rennt.ch/jar2.png))</sub>

But all classes are included in the jar, also the class `ServiceProvider`, which includes the `getAll()`-method:

**Assembled Jar:**

[image]
<sub>(source: [rennt.ch](https://rennt.ch/jarc.png))</sub>

So, what could be the problem here?

- Did we something wrong with building the JAR?
- Is there some kind of classpath problem?

We are grateful for any assistance!